# Working against a Secure-Channel with Security-Exit using XMS .NET API

Tags: c#, security, ibm-mq, xms

I own the following findings in order to work againts WMQ Secure-Channel:

1. Defined [Secure-Channel](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/integration/wmq/ssl.html) in the WMQ farm
2. Public/Private keys
3. Unmanaged [Security-Exit](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmbhelp/v7r0m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.mft.doc/ap12500_.htm) assembly

My question is how to utilize these resources and interact with a *Secure Channel* using the XMS API? (Using C#)

This is what I've tried so far, but without success:

```
private IConnectionFactory CreateConnectionFactory()
{
    XMSFactoryFactory factoryFactory = XMSFactoryFactory.GetInstance(XMSC.CT_WMQ);

    IConnectionFactory connectionFactory = factoryFactory.CreateConnectionFactory();

    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_HOST_NAME, _wmqHostName);
    connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_PORT, _wmqPort);
    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CHANNEL, _wmqChannel);
    connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, XMSC.WMQ_CM_CLIENT_UNMANAGED);
    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, _wmqQueueManager);
    connectionFactory.SetIntProperty(XMSC.WMQ_BROKER_VERSION, 0);
    connectionFactory.SetStringProperty(XMSC.WMQ_SECURITY_EXIT, "MySecurityExitName");

    return (connectionFactory);
}
```

I get the following error when calling it:

> CWSMQ0006E: An exception was received during the call to the method
>   ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection: CompCode: 2, Reason: 2195 . During
>   execution of the specified method an exception was thrown by another
>   component. See the linked exception for more information.

**UPDATE:**

I found the following Technote which describes my problem and its *possible* (not tested) solution:

https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC82112

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured-out that you can't use an unmanaged *Security Exit* assembly with [IBM.XMS API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024064) (`IBM.XMS.dll`), and this is what I currently have.

From the XMS docs:

> **[XMSC.WMQ_SECURITY_EXIT](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.xms.doc/props/prx_wmq_send_exit.html)**
>
> This property is relevant only when an application connects to a queue
>   manager in managed client mode. Also, **only managed exits are
>   supported**.

Eventually, I came up with replacing the usage of the XMS API with the [MQ Classes for .NET](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.mq.csqzav.doc/un10210_.htm) (Native .NET API of IBM for WMQ) which does support using an unmanaged *Security Exit*, by setting its `MQC.SECURITY_EXIT_PROPERTY` property (should be served in the form of a `Hashtable` entry). To be more specific, this is the assembly: `amqmdnet.dll`

Answer (score 4):

Good that you found that Technote.  Also make sure that...

- If doing mutual authentication (SVRCONN channel is set to `SSLCAUTH(REQUIRED)`) that the app's personal certificate [has a label matching the service account](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q014220_copy.htm).  Example, if the app is running as `dotnetacct` the label of the personal cert in its keystore would be `ibmwebspheremqdotnetacct`.
- Get the channel running without SSL or an exit first.  Then do server-authenticated SSL, then mutually authenticated SSL, then add the exit back in.  This isolates problems.
- Use the latest WMQ client.  I do not mean the latest fix pack for v7.0 or v7.1 but the latest v7.5 (as of this writing) client.  Download as [SupportPac MQC75](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMQC75).  Later clients are compatible with back-level QMgrs and they have more fixes/features.
- Install the *full* client and not just the classes or assemblies you think you need.  This gets you all sorts of utilities such as client-side tracing.
- Use the `amqssslc` sample to test your channel and certificates.  This is usually at `C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\WebSphere MQ\tools\c\Samples\Bin\amqssslc.exe` and is one of the utilities supplied when installing the full client.
- Go to the [WMQ SupportPacs page](http://ibm.co/SupptPacs) and look for [MH03 WebSphere MQ SSL Configuration Checker](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMH03) and [MO04 WebSphere MQ SSL Wizard](http://ibm.co/SupptPacMO04).  These can help with configuration and problem diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks Rob, When using a Security Exit, do I need to add more properties when constructing the Connection Factory in order to support the Secure Channel?

Comment: If that's a server-side exit, then the only properties you can add from the client side are the ID and password.  All other fields accessible to the exit, such as the certificate details, are provided by the connection request automatically.  However, exits can be client-side as well and if you have that, the answer depends on the exit itself.

Comment: There are two kinds of Security-Exits?

Comment: It is possible to run a server-side-only exit such as BlockIP2 or to run a pair of exits that talk to each other, with one at the server and one at the client or remote QMgr.  http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q010640_.htm